# Restart Shell in Vagrant

Tags: node.js, vagrant, nvm

I'm provisioning a VirtualBox server running Ubuntu Trusty using Vagrant and installing nvm. After installation I am given the following instructions:

```
    Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm
```

When I install manually this is simple (I log out and back in) but how can I automate this in the vagrantfile?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a shorthand for "restart your shell". Starting a new login shell with something like `exec bash --login` (with suitable adaptations for other shells) should accomplish the same thing, but isn't easily scriptable (that is, the currently executing script will terminate).

In reality, I would guess sourcing the updated dot files should suffice. I.e. if `$HOME/.bashrc` was updated,

```
. $HOME/.bashrc
```

would bring in the changes to the current script in the vast majority of cases. (If something was removed, sourcing will obviously not remove that setting from the current environment in the typical case.)

Of course, if the process which would print this prompt has already terminated, new scripts you run should already receive the updated environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the exact same thing. Facing the same issue with `nvm`.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find anything so far with regards to 'restarting' the terminal, but I followed the suggestion from the `nvm` install script and it seems to have worked. I was able to install node.

My `Vagrantfile` looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  config.vm.box_version = "20220517.0.0"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "setup.sh", privileged: false
end
```

Where the `setup.sh` contains:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get nvm 
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion

# Install Node 16
nvm install 16
```

Result
[image: Result]

As mentioned, have not yet found a way to 'restart' the terminal - but would also like to know how that's done.